# ¿Cómo conseguir que dos Divs se desplacen a diferente velocidad al hacer scroll?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, scroll, css-transform

Estoy trabajando en una web y necesitaría conseguir el siguiente efecto al hacer scroll.
Tengo dos contenedores, uno con imágenes y otro con texto que se superpone al primero. Hasta aquí todo bien. La idea es que al hacer scroll, el div con las imágenes se desplace ligeramente mas lento que el de texto. Algo así como un parallax, es decir, como si se encontrasen en capas diferentes.
Lo he intentado de varias maneras pero no consigo que me funcione.

Os dejo el código base que tengo con la esperanza de que alguno me pueda ayudar.

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.image-container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.text-container {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="item-galery" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any">
    <img class="item-galery" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any">
    <img class="item-galery" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p class="item-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p class="item-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p class="item-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: El efecto se llama parallax y necesitas javascript para implementarlo. Echa un vistazo a http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ y https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ . Hasta donde yo sé no se puede implementar únicamente con HTML/CSS. Edito: acabo de ver en tu pregunta que conoces el término pero parece que lo consideras una cosa diferente. Hazme saber qué duda tienes para aplicarlo.

Comment: Hola Luis. Ante todo gracias por tu respuesta. Correcto, conozco el término parallax y sus aplicaciones. Sin embargo, no tengo muy claro como puedo conseguir aplicarlo en los ejemplos que me enlazas. Tenía entendido que era posible conseguirlo mediante css y html con las propiedades transform/translate pero no he dado con la clave.

Answer (score 0):

La velocidad de la capa se controla mediante una combinación de los valores de traducción Z y perspectiva. Los elementos con valores Z negativos se desplazarán más lentamente que aquellos con un valor positivo. Cuanto más lejos esté el valor de 0, más pronunciado será el efecto de parallax (es decir, translateZ (-10px) se desplazará más lentamente que translateZ (-1px)).

ejemplo con tu codigo aqui

https://codepen.io/DerLeguan/pen/vaVmYq?editors=0100

para mas información revisar esta publicación 
https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Saludos, me cuenta como te va.